# Connect local MongoDB using static public IP from Mongo Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have installed MongoDB and created a Database from the command line. and connected to Mongo Compas using Hostname `local` and port `27017`. But If am trying to connect using my Public Static IP, it gives an error.

How to connect using my public IP.?

Comment: Is your mongodb allowing connections from anywhere other than 127.0.0.1? Look in the config file and find the `bindIp` directive and see what it says.

Comment: @codemonkey `net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1` in config file

Comment: `net:   port: 27017   bindIp: 0.0.0.0` set in config file @codemonkey

Comment: Now restart mongodb and you should be good to go.